# Normalize the Multiple document to single document in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
  "_id": "null",
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "abc",
      "id": "123"
    },
    {
      "name": "xzy",
      "id": "123"
    }

  ]
}
```

**Explanation:**  the `name` value will become an object name. also want to convert it into one single document, that contains all the objects. `abc` and `xyz` is dynamically coming as a parameter.

Expected Output.

```
{
    "data": {
      "abc": {
        "name": "abc",
        "id": "100"
      },
      "xyz": {
        "name": "xzy",
        "id": "123"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
db.testCollection.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            "array": {
                $map: {
                    input: "$data",
                    as: "item",
                    in: {
                        k: "$$item.name",
                        v: {
                            "name": "$$item.id",
                            "id": "$$item.name"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$array" },
    {
        $group: { 
            _id: "$null", 
            "data": { $push: "$array" }
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            "data": { $arrayToObject: "$data" }
        }
    }
]);
```

Comment: I think it will be much simpler with `$facet`. Need to try.

Comment: thanks for the response, but is there a way, if we did not specify the fields in v, but we call all values.  right now you mention only 2, what happens if I have 20--30, should I have to mention all of them?  `v: {  "name": "$$item.id", "id": "$$item.name"}`